# array of zeros minus 1 gives array of 255?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code:

```
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype='uint8')
a-1
```

Why do I get:

```
array([255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

As a result?

And not:

```
array([-1, -1, -1,...], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: "unsigned" is what the `u` in `uint` stands for. They don't have a sign, so they can't be negative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are using the [`uint8`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html) Data Type, which is an unsigned integer with 8 bits.

Its range is [0, 255], since `uint8` has 8 bits. Therefore, the maximum number that can be represented with this datatype is `2^8 - 1 = 256 - 1 = 255` (since 0 is included). When you subtract 1 from 0, you go from `00000000` to `11111111`. This is called an [underflow](https://medium.com/3-min-blockchain/understanding-uint-overflows-and-underflows-solidity-ethereum-8603339259e6).

Answer (score 2):

Type [`uint8`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html) is an unsigned integer of 8 bits, that means its range is `0` to `2^8-1` which is `0` to `255`. If you now subtract 1 from 0 you go one below the minimum and wind up at the maximum of 255 due to how numbers are represented in the computer.